# Missing artifactId in pom and error in find parent?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am new in Java. I want to make a web service from document
"[Implementing a simple OWS service](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/ows-services/implementing.html)", but in the pom file there are two errors:

> Missing artifact org.geoserver:main:jar:2.2.0

and

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find
>   org.geoserver:community:pom:2.2.0 in http://repo.opengeo.org was
>   cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of opengeo has elapsed or updates are forced
>   and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

What shoud I do?

Comment: thnx for your help but after i change version to 1.7.0 this error is appeared: in next comment

Answer (score 1):

If I look at the MvnRepository [Site](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver/main), I see that **org.geoserver.main** only has up to version 1.7.0 you should probably use that version. same for [community](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver/community).

Here are the dependencies just in case.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>community</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at the opengeo Maven Repository that is in your error message, looks like version 2.2.0 of the artifact is not there. It does not have 1.7.0 either. But I see other versions like 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5. You should probably use them. Take a look at the repository [main](http://repo.opengeo.org/org/geoserver/main/) & [community](http://repo.opengeo.org/org/geoserver/community/) and choose the version you want.

Comment: there is a version 2.2, but you should go for the 2.2.5 which is probably a bugfix release and should be compatible with 2.2 (if they follow semantic versioning).

Answer (score 0):

Ihave the same problem when learning the document "Implementing a simple OWS service",  Thanks for the Vikram , I edit the "2.2.0" to "2.2.5",then right cliked the project Maven4MyEclipse->Update Dependencies and Update Project Configuration, the errors in the pom.xml disappear,then mvn clean install, it is ok!
So “Take a look at the repository main & community and choose the version you want.”